# How customize registration in Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, registration, multiple-users

Is it possible to divide users into sections of the site? (different audience for different sections of the site)
For example, in one page (section "Books") registration for lovers of literature. In another page (section "Creating sites") - registration for programmers.

Or something like that. Please help!

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Thx, but how? Please, help